# initializer element is not constant - avr gcc

Tags: c, static, initialization, enumeration, avr-gcc

I have a simple code of seven segment deceleration :

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
int dp=1<<0;
int a=1<<1;
int b=1<<2;
int c=1<<3;
int d=1<<4;
int e=1<<5;
int f=1<<6;
int g=1<<7;
int ss[]={
    a|b|c|d|e|f,
    b|c,
    a|b|g|e|d,
    a|b|g|c|d,
    f|g|b|c,
    a|f|g|c|d,
    a|f|g|c|d|e,
    a|b|c,
    a|b|c|d|e|f|g,
    a|b|c|d|f|g,
    0x00
};
int main()
{
 while(1){}
}
```

But this gives me error when I am trying to generate `.hex` from this `.c` code:

Here is the error:

```
main.c:12: error: initializer element is not constant

main.c:12: error: (near initialization for 'ss[0]')
...
```

Same for all element..

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to ensure they *are* constants (available at compile time), by changing it to:

```
#define dp 0x01
#define a  0x02
#define b  0x04
#define c  0x08
#define d  0x10
#define e  0x20
#define f  0x40
#define g  0x80
```

I wouldn't worry too much about making them `1<<n` values since the number of times you'll have to change it will be vanishingly small.

---

Changing them to `const int` doesn't seem to help. I suspect `constexpr` would be an ideal solution for this, except for the fact it's C++ :-)

---

If you have binary constants available to you, you may also want to lokk into something like:

```
static const int sevenSegMap[] = {
    // .abcdefg
     0b01111110,  // or use 0xfe if no binary constants.
     0b00110000,
     : and so on
     0b01111011,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables with the static storage duration shall be initialized with compile-time constant expressions.

Instead of the set of the variables use an enumeration. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum
{
 dp=1<<0,
 a=1<<1,
 b=1<<2,
 c=1<<3,
 d=1<<4,
 e=1<<5,
 f=1<<6,
 g=1<<7
};

int ss[]={
    a|b|c|d|e|f,
    b|c,
    a|b|g|e|d,
    a|b|g|c|d,
    f|g|b|c,
    a|f|g|c|d,
    a|f|g|c|d|e,
    a|b|c,
    a|b|c|d|e|f|g,
    a|b|c|d|f|g,
    0x00
};

int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}
```